# AutoMapper: "Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type" error when mapping to a dictionary

Tags: .net-core, automapper

I am using Automapper to try and convert an object to a dictionary<string, string> but am getting the following error `AutoMapper: Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type`
Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error and how to accomplish this? I am using version 10.1.1. Mapping config below:

```
CreateMap<ImageUploadModel, Dictionary<string, string>>()
           .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(sourceMember => new Dictionary<string, string> {
               {"ClaimOID", sourceMember.ClaimOID.ToString()},
               {"ClaimNumber", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceMember.ClaimNumber) ? "undefined" : sourceMember.ClaimNumber},
               {"CountyCrop", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceMember.CountyCrop) ? "undefined" : sourceMember.CountyCrop},
               {"PolicyNumber", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceMember.PolicyNumber) ? "undefined" : sourceMember.PolicyNumber},
               {"DirectionDegrees", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceMember.DirectionDegrees) ? "undefined" : sourceMember.DirectionDegrees},
               {"DirectionText", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceMember.CountyCrop) ? "undefined" : sourceMember.DirectionText},
               {"Elevation", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceMember.Elevation) ? "undefined" : sourceMember.Elevation},
               {"Latitude", sourceMember.Lat.ToString()},
               {"Longitude", sourceMember.Lng.ToString()},
               {"ImageID", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceMember.ImageID) ? "undefined" : sourceMember.ImageID},
               {"Notes", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceMember.Notes) ? "undefined" : sourceMember.Notes},
               {"TakenBy", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceMember.TakenBy) ? "undefined" : sourceMember.TakenBy},
               {"TimeTaken", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceMember.TimeTaken) ? "undefined" : sourceMember.TimeTaken},
               {"Title", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceMember.Title) ? "undefined" : sourceMember.Title},
               {"Unit", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceMember.Unit) ? "undefined" : sourceMember.Unit},
        }));
```

If I create an object containing a dictionary and map to that like below, it works just fine.

```
public class MyObject { 
    public Dictionary<string, string> MyDictionary { get; set; }
}

CreateMap<ImageUploadModel, MyObject>()
           .ForMember(dest => dest.MyDictionary, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => new Dictionary<string, string> {...}
```

I have seen a ton of examples mapping directly to the object like this all the time `.ForMember(dest => dest,...`, but it seems to be what is causing the issue. Ideas, solutions, suggestions appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu  that is completely irrelevant for what I am trying to achieve.  Thanks for looking though.